# Distributed server model

Tags: python, distributed-computing

Lets say I have 100 servers each running a daemon - lets call it `server` - that server is responsible for spawning a thread for each user of this particular service (lets say 1000 threads per server). Every `N` seconds each thread does *something* and gets information for that particular user (this request/response model cannot be changed). The problem I a have is sometimes a thread hangs and stops doing *something*. I need some way to know that users data is stale, and needs to be refreshed.

The only idea I have is every `5N` seconds have the thread update a MySQL record associated with that user (a `last_scanned` column in the users table), and another process that checks that table every `15N` seconds, if the `last_scanned` column is not current, restart the thread.

Comment: When the thread stops doing something, is that expected behaviour or is it due to an error?

Comment: Due to an error - I should specify that the thread hangs (and yes, I should also fix the error so this wouldn't happen in the first place, but lets ignore that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to handle this is to have the threads report their status back to the server daemon. If you haven't seen a status update within the last 5N seconds, then you kill the thread and start another.

You can keep track of the current active threads that you've spun up in a list, then just loop through them occasionally to determine state.

You of course should also fix the errors in your program that are causing threads to exit prematurely.

Premature exits and killing a thread could also leave your program in an unexpected, non-atomic state. You should probably also have the server daemon run a cleanup process that makes sure any items in your queue, or whatever you're using to determine the workload, get reset after a certain period of inactivity.

Comment: That is certainly a better modle, but what would happen if the server daemon died (power outage, hardware failure, etc..)? I still feel like there needs to be some kind of persistant storage so if the server daemon dies, it would either know the users it was holding on to, or users that need to be scanned.

Comment: I assumed you had some sort of persistent storage already to do the work. Generally people will use a queue for this sort of thing. You might check out RabbitMQ for that.